# How can I Optimize the copy time in java?

Tags: java, performance, io

Is it possible to make the execution time faster?

```
import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.pdf");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test_copy.pdf");

    int c;
    while ( (c = in.read()) != -1 )
        out.write(c);

    in.close();
    out.close();

    System.out.println("Took " + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000_000 + "ms to finish");

  }    
}
```

Comment: Yep. Google it, you'll find it. By the way this code can be shrinked down to one line using `Files.copy`

Comment: What's wrong with people these days when they can't find *anything* from the biggest search engine in the world. Googling is a lot easier than programming after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a buffer of a fixed-size will probably yield better performance as you will be reading more than 1 byte of data at a time. This is done by calling [`read(b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) and giving an initialized byte array.

However, I strongly recommend that you don't reinvent the wheel. You can use the facilities provided since Java 7 with [Java NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) ([`Files.copy(source, target, options...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)):

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("test.pdf"), Paths.get("test_copy.pdf"));
```

If you want more control on the copy, you can give [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html) to this call as the third variable arguments, like [`StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html#REPLACE_EXISTING) that will replace the target file if it already exists.

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("test.pdf"), Paths.get("test_copy.pdf"), StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` would make it more efficient, but it's even better to not reinvent the wheel :

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("test.pdf"), Paths.get("test_copy.pdf"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Files.copy(Paths.get("test.pdf"), Paths.get("test_copy.pdf"));

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.println("Took " + time + "ms to finish");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java Run-time and call the OS specific commands to do the job. It will make sure copy will happens on OS level.